# flutter hive database delete data when user update the app

Tags: database, flutter, dart, nosql, flutter-hive

i am using flutter hive in my app that i published on store
i face some issue form some my users
the users told me  that when they updated the app form store,
the app deleted all data form app
but when i am trying to update my app on my device every thing is correct
how can i know why some users face this deleting issue ?

i am using model like this

```
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class ClassModelDb extends HiveObject
```

and i am using hive generator

hive_generator: ^2.0.1

i create uuid and store data

and i am using get it for injection
when user launch the app i use this code

```
await Hive.initFlutter();
Hive.registerAdapter(ClassModelDbAdapter());
var classDB = await Hive.openBox<ClassModelDb>(ClassDBTableName);
```

how to fix this problem